# Enum возвращает без пробелов

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enum

Пытаюсь получить массив или лист значений из `Enum` и затем сравнить со `string`. Проблема в том что значения я получаю, однако в массив они вносятся без пробелов, в результате чего я не могу сравнивать, поскольку в оригинальных строках есть пробелы, а из `Enum` получаю "однустроку" , хотя должно быть "одна строка"

Enum:

```
enum AccountType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Reservations")]
    Reservations = 0,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Corporate/Member Accounts")]
    CorporateOrMemberAccounts = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Unit Owners")]
    UnitOwners = 2
}
```

Result:

```
var attr = Enum.GetNames(typeof(AccountType)); // ["Reservations", "CorporateOrMemberAccounts", "UnitOwners"]
```

Как это поправить красиво?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получаете названия полей, а не их аттрибуты. То есть проблема не связана с пробелами вообще.

`Linq` и `Reflection` - эта ядерная смесь достанет вам что угодно и откуда угодно.

```cs
string[] attr = typeof(AccountType)
               .GetFields()
               .Select(f => f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false))
               .Where(a => a.Length > 0)
               .Select(a => ((EnumMemberAttribute)a[0]).Value)
               .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, attr));
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Reservations
Corporate/Member Accounts
Unit Owners
```

Но для таких данных я бы не стал использовать `enum`, а сразу какой-нибудь `Dictionary`, потому что в случае с `enum` придется редактировать код и пересобирать приложение. Лучше храните эти типы в базе данных, чтобы при случае можно было бы их туда оперативно добавить и через внешний ключ вяжитесь к табличке с ними.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private static string GetValue(AccountType type)
        {
            var enumType = typeof(AccountType);
            var memberInfos = enumType.GetMember(type.ToString());
            var enumValueMemberInfo = memberInfos.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DeclaringType == enumType);
            var valueAttributes =
                  enumValueMemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumMemberAttribute), false);
            return ((EnumMemberAttribute)valueAttributes[0]).Value;
        }
```

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetValue(AccountType.CorporateOrMemberAccounts)); //Corporate/Member Accounts 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Зайдём с другой стороны.

Суть вопроса - как сравнивать строки, содержащие и не содержащие пробелы?

Используем одну из перегрузок метода [String.Compare](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-5.0), которая принимает параметр [CompareOptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareoptions?view=net-5.0). Задаём `CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(
    "Corporate/Member Accounts",
    "Corporate/MemberAccounts",
    null,
    CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols)
);
```

Выведет `0` - то есть строки равны.
При необходимости укажите нужную культуру (вместо `null`).

PS: удалить пробелы с помощью `.Replace(" ", "")` слишком просто, поэтому отметём его с негодованием.

Comment: `Corporate/Member Accounts` vs `CorporateOrMemberAccounts` будет всегда `false`.