# Как получить описание атрибута класса C#?

Tags: c#

Есть класс с атрибутом:

```
[Description("Special Class")]
    public class Class1 {...}
```

Как мне в другом классе получить "Special Class"?

Comment: [Оно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245665/373567)

Comment: `((DescriptionAttribute) typeof(Class1).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)[0]).Description`